# Fail to install AWS Amplify CLI on Windows?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify-cli

I am trying to install AWS Amplify on Windows 10 machine, as mention in the [Amplify JavaScript - AWS documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart?sdk=js)

As a prerequisites, I have following versions installed

1. node - v10.14.2
2. npm - 6.4.1

when i shoot installation command `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`, it gives me following error.

[image]

`npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2`

`npm WARN relay-compiler@6.0.0 requires a peer of graphql@^14.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself`

`npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Can you help me to understand what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning the npm cache and try installing again

`npm rebuild`

Comment: try rebuild. if it doesnt work, i would try deleting the node_modules

Comment: I am installing ```aws-amplify/cli``` with global scope. So no node_modules folder created.

Answer (score 0):

On windows try this command -
`curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install-win -o install.cmd && install.cmd`